# Incorrect records from SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

So im trying to list the department locations, the project names associated with each department and the number of employees that work on each project.

There is a DeptLocations table(Attributes: Dnum, DLoc)

A Project table(Attributes:PName, Pnum, PLoc, DNum)

An Employee table (Attributes: FNAME, M, LNAME, SSN, BDATE, ADDRESS, S, SALARY, SUPERSSN, DNO)

And a Works_On table (Attributes: ESSN, PNO, HOURS).

This is my SQL query:

```
select DeptLocations.DLocation, Project.PName, count(ESSN) 

from Works_On, DeptLocations, Project, Department 

where DeptLocations.DLocation = Project.PLocation and Project.PNumber = Works_On.PNo
```

For some reason it only yields 1 record, when clearly there should be plenty more. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Use Group by with inner join  [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=792e353b8ebde094a6da356756058ee5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `group by` clause - as you've used aggregated function:

```
select 
  DeptLocations.DLocation, 
  Project.PName, 
  count(ESSN) 
from 
  Works_On 
  inner join Project on Project.PNumber = Works_On.PNo 
  inner join DeptLocations on DeptLocations.DLocation = Project.PLocation 
group by 
  DeptLocations.DLocation, Project.PName
```

Note: It's better to use explicit `join` instead of comma separated `join`.